# Laravel 5.4 sending emails

Tags: php, laravel, email

I have vps that has own email adresses, I want to test sending e-mails from that email address in my laravel API. I send the Post by postman to server on my local machine (homestead), I don't get any error users are registered in database but I don't receive an emails. Is there any way to configure this on local machine but be able to send emails from existing emails?

I'm using Laravel 5.4

**Mail function from authController**

```
    Mail::send('email.verify', ['name' => $name, 'verification_code' => $verification_code],
            function ($mail) use ($email, $name, $subject) {
                $mail->from('my@mailexample.pl', 'Wiadomość od CompanyName');
                $mail->to($email, $name);
                $mail->subject($subject);
            });
```

**Config/mail.php**

```
return [

    'driver' => 'mail',

    'host' => 'mail.mailexample.pl',


    'port' => 587,

    'from' => [
        'address' => 'my@mailexample.pl',

        'name' => 'Company Name',
    ],

    'encryption' => '',

    'username' => 'my@mailexample.pl',

    'password' => '',

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

Comment: Try adding `'pretend' => false`. The default value is `null` so I'm not sure if that defaults to true or false.

Comment: unfrotunatelly it doesn't change anything.

Comment: You need to install a `fake sendmail` in your homestead. [Example for Windows](https://www.glob.com.au/sendmail/)